# Printing odd numbers

Tags: c++

I would like help to find a short and small program in C++ to print out all odd number from 1 to 100 using a loop. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: This seems like homework to me. You should tag your question right. Plus, your question is not really language specific, it's more an algorithmic question.

Comment: Great, now we have a plethora of duplicates. Choose one :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i+=2 ) std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Err, guys...

There's also `for(int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2)`...

Answer (score 2):

you can just do -

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i = i + 2) 
{  
   std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bruteforce, stupid algorithm:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) if(i%2) std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

More intelligent algorithm:

```
for(short i = 1; i != 101; i+=2) std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I can beat Benoit ;-)

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i+=2) std::cout << i << std::endl;
```